# Better prior but worse estimation?

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

I have a model with a non gaussian prior. So the posterior probability is something like:

$p(\theta |x) \propto p(\theta)*p(x|\theta)$

$\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$

$p(x|\theta)$ is a gaussian density

$p(\theta)=g(\theta_1)f(\theta_2)$

where $g(\theta_1)$ is a gaussian density, while $f(\theta_2)$ can be a non gaussian density or a gaussian one.

$x=A\theta$ where $A$ is a constant matrix.

I want an estimate of $\theta_1$

SO first I do a marginalization in $\theta_2$ and then I do a MAP maximum a posteriori, by getting the maximum of this a posteriori probability $\theta_1$.

I have an estimate for the gaussian case and one for the non gaussian case.

I then generate data according to the NON-gaussian case: generate  $\theta_1$ that follows its gaussian density, generate $\theta_2$ with non gaussian density(for ex. a Rayleigh or a Chi-Squared) and then take as data $x=A\theta$.

Then I do a some sort of chi squared test to see which estimate it's better. I find that the non gaussian estimation (with the right a priori information) is worse than the other gaussian estimation!

I think that the problem is that with the non gaussian MAP there is some BIAS on my estimation. Have you any idea to find this BIAS or some theory to study?